# How to Save Emails showing raw Hyperlink Text

Tags: vba, outlook

We get automated emails from a third party that contains hyperlinks in a masked form (the link says other text instead of the address).
We want to export the raw link into either a text file or some other medium outside of Outlook, automatically, via a rule executing a script.

This does not work:

```vb
Sub ShowAllHyperlinkAddresses(objMail As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objItem As Object

Dim iCount As Integer
Dim Links As String
Dim objWordDocument As Word.Document

Set objHyperlinks = objWordDocument.Hyperlinks
Dim objHyperlink As Word.Hyperlink

For Each objItem In ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items
    iCount = iCount + 1
Next

If objHyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
    For Each objHyperlink In objHyperlinks
        strLink = objHyperlink.Address
        strLink = vbTab & "<" & strLink & ">"
        Links = Links & strLink
    Next
End If
        
Set objFileToWrite = CreateObject(“Scripting.FileSystemObject”)

objFileToWrite.OpenTextFile ("C:\Users\Wesley\Desktop" & CStr(iCount) & ".txt")
objFileToWrite.WriteLine Links
objFileToWrite.Close
objFileToWrite = Nothing

End Sub
```

My main goal is to end up with a text file that contains the raw hyperlinks.
We do not care about file names or anything like that as the file will be deleted shortly after saving.

Edit/Update:
My team sorted out what we needed using Python 3 along with win32com.

```
import win32com.client

outlook = 
win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
folder = outlook.Folders("YOUR_EMAIL_HERE")
inbox = folder.Folders("Inbox")
msg = inbox.Items
msgs = msg.GetLast()
body = msgs.body

links = re.findall(r'(https?://\S+)', body)
```

Pulls the most recent email and grabs its links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get an instance of the Word `Document` class from the received item:

```
Sub ShowAllHyperlinkAddresses(objMail As Outlook.MailItem)
  Dim iCount As Integer
  Dim Links As String
  Dim objWordDocument As Word.Document

  Set objWordDocument = objMail.GetInspector().WordEditor

  Set objHyperlinks = objWordDocument.Hyperlinks
  Dim objHyperlink As Word.Hyperlink

  If objHyperlinks.Count > 0 Then
       For Each objHyperlink In objHyperlinks
           strLink = objHyperlink.Address
           strLink = vbTab & "<" & strLink & ">"
           Links = Links & strLink
       Next
  End If

  iCount = ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items.Count

  Set objFileToWrite = CreateObject(“Scripting.FileSystemObject”)

  objFileToWrite.OpenTextFile ("C:\Users\Wesley\Desktop" & CStr(iCount) & ".txt")
  objFileToWrite.WriteLine Links
  objFileToWrite.Close
  objFileToWrite = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: ```Dim objWordDocument As Word.Document``` - Compile Error: User-Defined type not defined.

Comment: Solved by adding the Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library as a reference in the VBA editor from Outlook.

Comment: Script executes, does not put text file on desktop however.

Comment: Try run the code under the debugger. Create a new method which gets the currently selected item in Outlook and pass it to your function so you will be able to debug the code.